# Java call application servlet with relative path

Tags: java, http, servlets, get, relative-path

How to call application servlet from java class with relative path.

I want to call with GET method

```
/myServlet
```

from

```
myClass.
```

**EDIT**

So far i find:

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    URL url = null;

    try {

        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myApp/myServlet");

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
        result = in.readLine(); 

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { } 
    }
```

but as i said i want to call a servlet with relative path. Not to decler hostname and appName.

Comment: please explain a bit more. not clear.

Comment: Can you please show us the code ?

Comment: from where you are calling this class?

Comment: The question might be like, can we access a servlet using relative path? since  servlet is the part of same code base where he is trying to access. As he mentioned in the above code; instead of passing absolute URL in URL method can he pass relative URL to access the same servlet. **Current:** `url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myApp/myServlet");` **Expected:** `url = new URL("/myApp/myServlet");`